# Monodevelop build always successful

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, monodevelop, unityscript

I dont know why but now (it worked fine yesterday) when building my scripts is says Build successful every time even whern there are mistakes.
 I tried deleting the files in : `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Monodevelop` and even reinstall unity. 
Nothing worked. 
I dont know if this is related but since installing monodevelop I didnt have autocomplete, I saw an answer which said to resync the project but I dont know how.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thank you!